# Is there a mechanism that detects any changes in database schema?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, cdc

We frequently make changes to the database schema, e.g. adding new columns, moving data to other columns, etc.

Is there a mechanism able to detect these changes?

I tried change data capture CDC, for example (price = 200 -> 300), but I want to detect changes in the schema,  e.g. adding new tables, columns, moving data to other columns, etc.

Comment: CDC is for data capture, as the name says. Schema changes can be captured and monitored through [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), [DDL triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16), auditing

Comment: What are you trying to do? [This series of articles](https://blog.sqlterritory.com/2018/12/11/5-ways-to-track-database-schema-changes-part-4-ddl-trigger/) shows how to use various techniques. The best option depends on your actual scenario and requirements.

Comment: If you want to version the schema or deploy changes you may not even need schema change detection. You could use SSMS/Azure Data Studio to generate and version a database project, extract (and store) the schema as a Dacpac, or compare *and* apply differences between databases, projects, dacpacs, or databases and dacpacs. You could version your database schema in Git by regularly updating it with the changes found in the production database

Comment: Rather than reactively trying to audit things after they happen you are better off making sure your database is source controlled (so change history available there) and changes only made through a deployment pipeline that pulls from that

Answer (score 0):

A [DDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16) trigger or [ExtendedEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr?view=azuresql) will capture schema changes.

> moving data to other columns, etc.

CDC will capture data changes.

Comment: This question is too open ended. The answer could vary from a real-time DDL trigger to ad-hoc updating a database project for schema tracking purposes, with XEs in between.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, agreed. I just called out a couple of building blocks that could be used as part of a solution.

Comment: I thought of these two, but as I was googling for more I saw some articles that mentioned change approval. That's something that's probably better to do with database projects.